# Building a REST API in Flask getting a 400 error when trying to make a POST request

Tags: python, curl, flask

I'm following a tutorial [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask), and I'm at the part where we first start setting up the create_task function. I keep getting the error

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
 <title>400 Bad Request</title>
 <h1>Bad Request</h1>
 <p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

I'm on windows and using the cURL command

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"title":"Read a book"}' http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/tasks
```

Here's my code

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, make_response, request

app = Flask(__name__)

tasks = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'title': u'Buy groceries',
        'description': u'Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol',
        'done': False
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'title': u'Learn Python',
        'description': u'Need to find a good Python tutorial on the Web',
        'done': False
    }
    ]

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'404': 'Resource Not Found'}), 404)

@app.route('/api/v1.0/tasks/<int:task_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_task(task_id):
    task = [task for task in tasks if task['id'] == task_id]
    if len(task) == 0:
        abort(404)
    return jsonify({'task': task[0]})

@app.route('/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['POST'])
def create_task():
    if not request.json or not 'title' in request.json:
        abort(404)
    task = {
        'id': tasks[-1]['id'] + 1,
        'title': request.json['title'],
        'description': request.json.get('description', ""),
        'done': False
    }
    tasks.append(task)
    return jsonify({'task': task}), 201

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I've tried everything I can think of. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I copy pasted this code and was able to successfully POST and GET. I even copied the curl command too.

Comment: Th same issue is occurring for me (also following the tutorial). What did you end up doing to successfully create the POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your code works perfectly fine. Try reinstalling flask.**

Instead of cURL you can also try sending the request through POSTMAN (Chrome Plugin).

**Through cURL:**
[image: Right side window shows the Result]

Right side window shows the Result

**Through Postman (Chrome Plugin):**

[image]

Comment: What is the python version you are using?

Comment: Sorry, that previous one worked I just forgot to send it as json. Thank you